# Load new advanced field on all field types

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to add a new field to the advanced tab on the Gravity Forms form builder page. I have the following code and **it works for text fields only**.

```php
function add_forms_meta_tag( $position, $form_id ) {

    if ( 25 == $position ) : ?>

        <li class="meta_tag_setting field_setting">
            <label for="field_meta_tag" class="section_label">
                <?php _e( 'Meta Tag' ); ?>
                <?php gform_tooltip( 'form_field_meta_tag_tooltip' ) ?>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="field_meta_tag" id="field_meta_tag" class="field_meta_tag" onchange="SetFieldProperty('MetaTag', this.value);" />
        </li>

    <?php endif;

}

function init_meta_tag_js() {

    ?>

        <script type='text/javascript'>

            fieldSettings.text += ", .meta_tag_setting";

            jQuery(document).bind('gform_load_field_settings', function(event, field, form) {

                jQuery('#field_meta_tag').val( field.MetaTag );

            });

        </script>

    <?php

}

function add_meta_tag_tooltip( $tooltips ) {

    $tooltips['form_field_meta_tag_tooltip'] = 'asdf';

    return $tooltips;

}
```

When I look at the source code for the email field type (*as an example*), the field is listed there and it does also save the value if you enter one, but Gravity Forms is setting it to `display: none;`. I've read [the documentation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_advanced_settings/) but nothing seems to indicate why this is happening.

How can I ensure this field is shown for all field types, not just text fields?

Comment: check out this link https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/dynamic-field-duplication-in-gravity-forms/

Comment: That's not quite what I'm after. I'm wanting to have the custom field appear on each field type (like email or checkbox) much like the default value field but it's only appearing for text input fields.